# Torques acting on a decelerating box - Maximum height of the box so it does not tip over

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque

A square based box (length and width = 1m) lies on a horizontal surface on a train. The train decelerates constantly at 5ms^-2 till it stops. Determine the maximum height of the box so that it does not tip over.

Assumptions: - Box does not slide
             - Equal weight distribution

My answer:
the 2 forces providing rotational torque are 1. weight of box acting on the centre of mass and 2. the horizontal deceleration of the object (5ms^-2) also acting on the centre of mass. 
Taking moments at the pivot point - corner of the box:

Torque of 1. = 9.8M * 1/2 (M=mass of box)

Torque of 2. = -5M * h/2 (h= height of the box)

For the box not to tip:

1.+ 2. = 0

9.8M * 1/2 = 5M * h/2

9.8 = 5 *h

h= 9.8/5 = 1.96 m

Very simple calculation so I am worried it is incorrect...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I think it's correct.